# Efficient Numpy search in a non-monotonic array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to conduct something similar to `searchsorted`, but in the case where the array is not completely monotonic. Say I have a scalar, `c` and a 1D array `x`, I want to find the indices `i` of all elements such that `x[i] < c <= x[i + 1]`. Importantly, `x` is not completely monotonic.

The following code works, but I just would like to know if this is the most efficient way to do this, or if there is a simper way:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
c = 2.5
t = c > x[:-1]
u = c <= x[1:]
v = t*u
i = v.nonzero()[0]
```

Or in one line of code:

```
i = ( (c > x[:-1]) * (c <= x[1:] ).nonzero()[0]
```

Is this the most efficient way to recover these indices?

Two additional questions.

1. Is there an easy way to extend this to the case where `c` is a 1D array and `x` is a 2D array, where `c` has as many elements as "rows" in `x`, and I perform this search for each element of `c` in the corresponding "row" of `x`?
2. My ultimate goal is to do this with a three dimensional case. That is, suppose `c` is still a 1D vector with `n` elements. Now, let `x` be a 3D array, with dimensions `j` by `n` by `k`. Is there a way to do #1 above for each "submatrix" in `x`? Basically, performing #1 above `j` times.

For example:

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3],[1,2,3,1,2,3],[1,2,3,1,2,3])
x2 = x1 + 1
x = np.array([x1,x2])
c = np.array([1.5,2.5,3.5])
```

Under #1 above, when we compare c and x1, we would get: `[[0,4],[1,5],[]]`

When we compare c and x2, we would get: `[[],[0,4],[1,5]]`

Finally, under #2, I would like to get:

```
[[[0,4],[1,5],[]],
 [[],[0,4],[1,5]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could compare once to give us the boolean mask and re-use it with negation to get the other comparison array and also use slicing -

```
m = c > x
i = np.flatnonzero( m[:-1] & ~m[1:] )
```

We can extend it to `x` as `2D` and `c` as `1D` case with a loop, but do minimal computations with it by pre-computing on the masks generation in a vectorized manner, like so -

```
m = c[:,None] > x
m2 = m[:,:-1] & ~m[:,1:]
i = [np.flatnonzero( mi ) for mi in m2]
```

Comment: I now see how the `for` feature can be used to do each row separately. Apologies for editing the question once more, but can this be extended to loop through two dimensions of `x`?

Comment: @profj Would need a minimal sample and expected output or a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

On such task, numpy make too much comparisons. You can win a 5X factor with Numba. No difficulties to adapt for 3 dimensions.

```
@numba.njit
def ind(x,c):
    res = empty_like(x)
    i=j=0
    while i < x.size-1:
        if x[i]<c and c<=x[i+1]:
            res[j]=i
            j+=1
        i+=1 
    return res[:j]
```